# Share Classloader between multiple in Jetty Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, classloader, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm try to configure maven jetty plugin to start my war application, but it has some complications like as follow descriptions:

1º - It has dependencies with a ejb jar;
2º - It has dependencies with war (tag jstl:import context="nscl");
3º - The classloader between wars must be shareded.

So, I need some help to resolve the third problem. Looks my jetty plugin configuration in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
            <configuration>
                <useProvidedScope>true</useProvidedScope>
                <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/nscl/cntr</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <contextHandlers>
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                        <war>${contexto.war.path}</war>
                        <contextPath>/nscl</contextPath>
                    </contextHandler>
                </contextHandlers>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                        <value>test</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is, when jetty is starting the second war (context-path = nscl), I receive problems saying the classes used to start first war not exist to second, a sample is classes of spring framework.

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting Standard Servlet Spec behavior.

Your WebApp's cannot share the same ClassLoader.

That is a fundamental part of being a Servlet Spec WebApp, the ClassLoader isolation.

Attempting to force it will just create mysterious problems with the ClassLoader hierarchy (InvalidClassChange errors, memory leaks, GC failures, etc)

Perhaps you can detail *why* you think you need this.

As there's likely already a standard way to accomplish it using the features of the Servlet spec (and not fighting it).